# Automatic URL Parameter Encoding Failing

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

## Background

In `HomeController.cs` I have:

```
[HttpGet]
public GetPerson(string name)
{
    return View(new PersonModel { ... });
}
```

In `Global.asax.cs` I have:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

    routes.MapRoute(
        "Word", "person/{name}",
         new { controller = "Home", action = "GetPerson" });

    routes.MapRoute(
        "Default", "{controller}/{action}",
        new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" });
}
```

In `SomePage.cshtml` I have, effectively, this:

```
@{ var name = "Winston S. Churchill"; }
<a href="@Url.Action("GetPerson", "Home", new { name })">@name</a>
```

## Problem

If I click the link for Winston S. Churchill, I am routed to the URL `http://localhost/person/Winston%20S.%20Churchill`, which yields the standard 404 page:

> > > HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found
> > >
> > > The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.

**This only happens if the `name` variable contains a `.` (period).** All my code works perfectly fine when the name is, for example, `Winston Churchill`.

**How can I make ASP.NET MVC 3 percent-encode the `.` (period) in the URL?**

**Or, how can I make the routing work without `.` (period) being percent-encoded?**

## Unacceptable Workaround (if presented without justification)

If I change the route to the following, everything works.

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Word", "person",
     new { controller = "Home", action = "GetPerson" });
```

However, the URL becomes `http://localhost/person?name=Winston%20S.%20Churchill`, which isn't what I want. I want the `name` in the path part of the URL, not the query.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Routes which contain a period and unknown extension are interpreted by IIS as static files and not sent through the .NET pipeline. For example, the URL you cite is interpreted as a static file with a `%20Churchill` extension.

You can force ASP.NET to handle all requests by adding this to `web.config`:

```
<system.webServer>
  <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
</system.webServer>
```

You'll also need this, to handle `name` values that end with a period (as opposed to just containing one):

```
<system.web>
    <httpRuntime relaxedUrlToFileSystemMapping="true" />
</system.web>
```

All `/person/{name}` URLs will then be picked up by your ASP.NET code.

If you would rather not use this setting, the easiest workaround would be to use a custom encoding:

```
name.Replace(".","--")
```

Comment: Are there any safety issues with this that could be unexpected?

Comment: Also, while this works for `Winston S. Churchill` (I just tried it), it fails for `Albert Gore Jr.` (note period at end).

Comment: No safety issues, but it means that ASP.NET will try to process all requests so files that actually are static (images, CSS, etc.) will take a tiny bit longer to load. In practice, you are unlikely to notice a difference. To fix the issue with the terminating period, try adding `<httpRuntime relaxedUrlToFileSystemMapping="true" />` to `<system.web>`.

Comment: The issue with runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests is not really a security one, but with performance since all requests will be handled by managed modules even request for static files.

Comment: Excellent. My site has very little static content (shortcut icon is it so far). The two changes you outlined worked great. I'm going to edit your answer to highlight the `relaxedUrlToFileSystemMapping` setting.